# Error running rails 4 with mysql2 gem locked to 0.4.x (dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_server_init)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql-connector, mysql2

I am using Mac OS 10.14.6

I recently needed to upgrade to Ruby 2.4.9

Other gemfile dependencies drove mysql2 gem version up to 0.5.x

Ruby 2.4 does not support this 
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/950#issuecomment-377119554

So I locked my mysql2 version to 0.4.x

Additionally I am running mysql 5.6 and as a result of other errors I am using the following command to install mysql2 gem

`gem install mysql2 -v0.4.0 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6`

However, when I attempt to run rails I get the following errors

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_server_init
  Referenced from: /Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.4.9/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_server_init
  Referenced from: /Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.4.9/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have read this is possibly related to 32 vs 64 bit installation versions but using a cask version of mysql I am not certain how to ensure that I am installing the correct version of the gem.

Comment: How is Ruby installed? Are you using brew? I would recommend using something like RVM, then installing Ruby, the installing your gems again, and retrying.

Comment: @anothermh I used ruby-build to install the Ruby version and chruby to manage the ruby installations. I am using brew to install things such as openssl, ruby-build, etc.

Comment: Did you try RVM?